# Is it possible to place multiple collections into 1 collection in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migrate

I want to migrate from TFS to VSTS. Then I encountered a problem which is that I can only have one collection but I have multiple collections on my TFS server. I searched on the internet for an clear answer but couldn't find one.

So is it possible to integrate multiple collections into one collection?